# Include в заголовочных файлах

Tags: c++

Заметил, что в разных проектах C++ программисты по разному используют директиву **#include**

1) В первом случае **include** по максимуму прописывают в h-файлах, но уже не пишут в cpp-файлах. Т.е. делаешь включение одного заголовочного файла, а он уже тянет все инклуды в себе.

2) Во втором случае наоборот, в h-файлах почти нет **include**, но все эти **include** спишут в cpp-файлах. При этом, если есть некие общие классы, то могут сделать так:

- В начале заголовочного файла ставят пустое объявление класса: **class myClass;**. Но этот **include** будет в cpp-файле.
- В заголовочном файле вообще нет объявления внешних типов данных. Но всё работает если в cpp-файле подключать заголовочные файлы с описанием классов **перед** подключением зависимых заголовочных файлов, т.е. важен порядок

Вопросы у меня такие:

- Есть ли формальное наименование этих стилей компановки исходного кода?
- Как делать правильно, а как делать нельзя?
- Хочется изучить эту тему от и до. С чего начать?

Comment: Второй подход лучше, так как не создаёт излишние зависимости. Я стараюсь писать как можно больше в `.cpp`-файлах, и выносить в `.h` только когда этого не избежать. Однако, часто используемые зависимости лучше вынести в отдельный `.h`.

Если вы пользуетесь MSVC, общую неизменяемую часть лучше вынести в `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Спасибо VladD, попробую такой подход

Answer (score 10, accepted):

По моему опыту в большинстве случаев работает такой простой критерий:

"минимальная" программа с **любым** из Ваших инклюд-файлов должна собираться.

Например:

```
// t.cpp
#include "myincl1.h"

int main () {
   return 0;
}
```

это весь текст

```
g++ t.cpp
```

Компиляция должна успешно пройти.

А в "myincl1.h" при этом желательно включать минимальное количество других `.h` файлов (как системных, так и собственных).

И конечно, не забывайте писать

```
#ifndef _MYINCL1_H
#define _MYINCL1_H
....
#endif // _MYINCL1_H
```

в начале и конце своих `.h`.

Собственно, это требование к правильно написанному заголовочному файлу. Естественно, не должно быть никаких зависимостей от порядка включения файлов.

Иногда для сокращения писанины удобно написать два-три "обобщающих" `.h`-файла, которые включают большинство  собственных и системных `.h`, нужных для конкретной программы (используются во многих ее модулях).

Comment: Очень интересный критерий оценки, avp, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 7):

> Хочется изучить эту тему от и до. С чего начать?

Книжек про это не встречал

> Есть ли формальное наименование этих стилей компановки исходного кода?

Не знаю

> Как делать правильно, а как делать нельзя?

Вот мои рассуждения:

Думаю следует различать 2 ситуации:

1. Заголовочный файл содержит какие-то функции / классы (объявление + реализацию), которые могут быть использованы в разных проектах в самых разных местах. Такой файл должен включать в себя все заголовочные файлы, которые ему могут понадобится. По принципу "подключил и забыл", чтобы не нужно было самому подключать какие-то дополнительные заголовочные файлы.
2. Заголовочный файл (.h) содержит описание класса / функций, а файл (.cpp) содержит их реализацию. В таком случае или в .h файл включатся только те инклуды, которые содержат объекты, присутствующие в описании классов / функций (например `std::vector`), или не включается ничего, а всё-всё-всё включается в .cpp файл. Первый способ позволяет не плясать с порядком инклудов в .cpp файле, второй не делать лишние инклуды, но требует правильного порядка подключения.

Правило подключения имхо очень простое, его не сложно запомнить и не сложно ему следовать:

```
в файле MyClass.cpp

#include <vector> (1) сначала подключаются файлы стандартной библиотеки

#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp> (2) затем подключатся файлы 3rd-party библиотек, 
                                   объекты и функции которых Вы используете в
                                   своём коде

#include <MyInclude/Helpers.h> (3) свои внутренние заголовочные файлы

#include <MyClass.h> (3) свой заголовочный файл, реализацию для которого мы пишем
```

Пустое объявление myClass имхо хорошее решение (следуя принципу чем меньше инклудов и чем они "локальнее", тем лучше), но есть подводный камень (см. для чего нужен `boost::checked_delete`). Обычно пустые объявления используют для указателей, нужно проследить чтобы эти указатели не удалялись.

И не забывать про существование precompiled headers

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 6):

Трудно однозначно ответить на этот вопрос. Скорее, тут дело вкуса или даже масштаба задачи: если это какой-нибудь опенсорсный проект, то тогда для удобства других целесообразно поместить все инклуды в заголовочный файл, если же вы решаете задачу для себя( проводите исследование, к примеру ), то о таком подходе разбиения кода можно даже не думать особо - тут достаточно и одного файла, где будет расположено все, все, все. А в целом, логическое разбиение кода - хорошая привычка.

Comment: В моей практике есть негативный пример для первого подхода.

В одном проекте часто приходится вносить изменения в базовые заголовочные файлы, т.к. туда вынесено очень много различных функций, в том числе inline, а заодно и все нужные include. После этого приходится пересобирать проект целиком, т.к. почти все h и cpp файлы включают эти базовые заголовки.

Видимо, уже давно пора разделить эти файлы на кучу более мелких :)

Answer (score 4):

Ну в случае "всеобъемлющих" header-файлов - может получиться циклическая зависимость. И вполне вероятно если не придерживаться четко какому-либо "стилю" , то группа разработчиков вполне может достичь такого эффекта. В результате "сильно связанную" h-ку нельзя использовать в зависящем проекте, где и без нее своих объявлений хватает.

Поэтому мой вариант в идеале писать так в h-файлах для поддержания порядка:

```
#ifndef SOME_NEED_H
 #error Пожалуйста подключите SOME_NEED_H
#endif
```

Так загадки в порядке нет.
Ну а если лень - тогда действительно pch (аккуратно составленный) в помощь. 
Я за минимализм в h-ках и за some_header_tmpl.h (где есть все необходимое) для cpp.

Answer (score 3):

> "минимальная" программа с любым из
> Ваших инклюд-файлов должна собираться.

Мне одному кажется, что это очень странный критерий?
Хотелось бы предостеречь автора вопроса, от столь интересных критериев.

По-хорошему в хидере должно быть как можно меньше #include.
Делается это как правило для того, чтобы компилироваться проект быстро [и только потом уже, чтобы собирать нормальные библиотеки, без лишних и никому не нужных зависимостей].

Comment: Я это понял так, что один заголовочный файл не должен зависеть от другого, и не выдавать ошибку если забыли подключить что-то кроме него.
Например при подключении mysql.h нужно обязательно подключить windows.h перед ним, иначе будет ошибка при компиляции.

 #include <windows.h>

 #include <mysql.h> 

Т.е. критерий от AVP (автор совета) заголовочный файл mysql.h не проходит.

Comment: Имхо критерий абсолютно верный, время компиляции (и нервы разработчика) в противном случае с лихвой тратится на то, чтобы узнать какой include нужно подключить и в каком порядке. Для увеличения сборки проектов придумали ``precompiled headers`` и ``#pragma once``.

Comment: @Katilina: Это на мой взгляд баг на стороне `mysql.h`: header **обязан** включать всё, что ему требуется.

Comment: @ikonnov: Мне не кажется этот критерий странным. Если header'у `A` требуется header `B`, этот `B` должен быть включён так или иначе, либо из `A`, либо из всех тех, кто использует `A` (иначе не скомпилируется). Включение в `A` практически не увеличивает время компиляции, если вы правильно используете include guards.

Comment: зачем же тогда forward declaration?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите, чтобы с вашими заголовочными файлами было как можно меньше неприятных сюрпризов - в модуле должны быть указаны все необходимые для него заголовочные файлы. Не следует полагаться на то, что один .h включит в себя другой.

Если Вы собираетесь всю жизнь работать с одним компилятором, причём одной версии, разницы Вы можете не увидеть. Но как правило, так не получается. И хорошо написанная программа на C++ должна подразумевать, что её будут собирать разными компиляторами, а иногда и на разных операционных системах. И если вы привыкли к "минимализму", который тут некоторые советуют, вы обнаружите, что в одних условиях Ваша программа собирается, в других нет, причём зависит это в буквальном смысле от фазы Луны. Дело в том, что в С++ (в отличие, допустим от Java, Oberon и даже Object Pascal) отсутствуют языковые средства поддержки модульности. Есть только раздельная компиляция. А для обеспечения модульности приходится применять костыли - #include, namespace и др. И неправильное их применение чревато тяжёлыми ошибками.

Чтобы не было циклических зависимостей, а также, чтобы модуль с большим количеством включённых заголовочных файлов не собирался слишком долго, существуют стражи компиляции (стражи включения, include guards) - [см. статью в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). И в грамотно написанном заголовочном файле их применение обязательно! К сожалению, некоторые сторонники "минимализма" здесь, боюсь, не подозревают об их наличии.

Совет собирать ссылки на часто используемые заголовочники в один "метазаголовочник" тоже, как правило, не очень хорош. Поменяете Вы один файл, а пересобираться будет десяток, причём большей частью тех, которым он совсем не нужен.
Прекомпиляция для больших проектов может быть хорошим решением, однако помните, что в разны компиляторах она может работать по-разному.

Возможно, я написал много букв, но мой совет - это совет человека, который много лет пишет переносимые программы под разные ОС. И у меня была возможность убедиться, что копеечная экономия на времени сборки порой оборачивается тяжёлыми проблемами.
Желаю удачи в написании грамотных программ на C++.

Comment: @DarkHobbit, если откровенно, то не понял, каким образом "минимализм" связан с проблемами модульности. IMHO как раз наоборот.

По поводу include guards Вы абсолютно правы и я тоже в своем ответе отмечал это:


    И конечно, не забывайте писать
       #ifndef _MYINCL1_H
    ....

А для "метазаголовочника", естественно, д.б. правило - менять его как можно реже, менять надо файлы, которые он подключает, ну, и само собой использовать `makedepend`.

--

Кстати, а в чем все-таки суть **Вашего совета?**

Comment: @avp: Проблема с минимализмом такая: если у одного компилятора header `<map>` #include'ит header `<vector>`, а у другого нет, то такой код:

    #include <map>
    map<int, vector<int>> m;

будет работать на первом компиляторе, и не будет переноситься на второй. То есть «минимальность» (а здесь мы как бы не включаем «лишний» `<vector>`, так как вроде и без него работает) мешает переносимости.

Comment: @VladD, это вообще вопрос переносимости (portability). Обычно решается директивами условной компиляции (\#ifdef ... и т.д. и т.п.)

Куча (просто огромная) примеров в /usr/include -) (и почти все удовлетворяют критерию "минимальности").

Вообще-то, может быть самым коротким и лучшим советом для ТС был бы - *почитай /usr/include*

Comment: @avp: Но если бы сразу написать

    #include <map>
    #include <vector>

— то проблема гарантированно не возникла бы нигде.

Comment: Справедливое замечание.

Answer (score 2):

Знаю, что тема давно устарела, но может кому-нибудь понадобится.
Второй случай, когда мы покдлючаем минимальное количество заголовочных файлов в .h хорошо помогает при уменьшении времени компиляции проекта, если он достаточно большой. Например, такой подход активно используется в Qt.