# Visual Studio 2012 - вынос функций, использующих OpenGL (GLU, GLUT), в отдельные файлы

Tags: project, ооп, c++, visual-studio, opengl

Мне необходимо вынести некоторые функции, использующие стандартные методы OpenGL в отдельный файл для удобства работы. Например, у меня есть такая:

```
// управлять перемещением камеры:
void moveCamera( float pp1, float pp2, float pp3, float pp4, float eX, float eY, float eZ)
{
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(pp1, pp2, pp3, pp4);
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (eX, eY, eZ, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Я (новичок) прочёл, что все **.cpp** файлы проекта (по крайней мере, включённые в solution VS), уже связаны друг с другом (поправьте меня, если я неправильно понял), т.е., главный файл (тот, который содержит **main()**/**_tmain()**) должен видеть все остальные и автоматически включать в код программы. Верно?
Однако, если я пытаюсь сделать задуманное, и просто создаю в решении файл, куда все эти функции переношу, оно говорит, что функции OpenGL "undefined". Я уверен, что решение здесь элементарно. Но мне оно неизвестно. Плз, если у вас оно есть (и оно работает), сообщите его мне!

UPD. Последовал совету, но проблема осталась. Вероятно, где-то ошибся. Но где?
Вот иллюстрация текущего состояния (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnIzX.gif):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Нет, неверно.

В C++ принята *раздельная* модель компиляции: каждый .cpp-файл компилируется сам по себе, полученные .obj-файлы «складываются» в одно приложение компоновщиком (известным также как linker). Это означает, в частности, что просто так один .cpp-файл не сможет увидеть функции, определённые в другом .cpp-файле, вы должны сами позаботиться о видимости.

Делайте следующее:

- Вынесите все нужные вам функции в отдельные .cpp-файлы (вы это уже, наверное, сделали).
- Для каждого .cpp-файла, кроме главного, создайте свой .h-файл, в который поместите *декларации* функций. (Вы же знаете, как правильно писать .h-файлы, да? Include guard и фсё такоэ.)
- Там, где вы используете функции из другого .cpp-файла, в начале должен быть `#include` соответствующего .h-файла. Например, если вы в `x.cpp` (или в `x.h`) используете функцию или тип, определённые в `y.cpp`, добавьте в начало `x.cpp` (или `x.h`, соответственно) `#include "y.h"`
- Не забудьте указать компоновщику, что он должен добавить функции OpenGL. (Свойства проекта -> компоновщик -> зависимости -> добавьте OpenGL32.lib, GLU32.lib, GLUT32.lib или что там говорит документация.) Иначе будете получать ошибки компоновки.

Comment: Спасибо и извините за поздний комментарий. Всё сделал как вы рекомендовали (вроде бы), но проблема осталась. Все библиотеки подключены (VS видит их в проекте как External Depencies), но отдельный файл их в упор не замечает (см. иллюстрацию в UPD). Возможно, я таки где-то совершил какую-то глупую ошибку. Но собственных идей пока нет :(

Answer (score 0):

Перенесите #include GL, GLU и glut в файл funx.cpp. Хотел сначала предложить перенести в funx.h, но [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275741/c-include-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85) объясняют, почему лучше в cpp файл.

Для лучшего понимания, объясню что такое директива #include. Перед компиляцией вместо директивы #include "header.h" подставляется всё содержимое заголовочного файла "header.h".
К примеру:

До препроцессирования (исходники):

---

Файл funx.cpp

```
#include "funx.h"

void Draw()
{
  // code
}
```

Файл funx.h

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Draw();
```

---

После препроцессирования:

Файл funx.cpp

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Draw();

void Draw()
{
  // code
}
```

*Ответил бы в комментарии, но там нету форматирования текста, а сейчас не хотелось бы этим пренебречь.*